# jQuery Scroll Next/Previous Div With Image Buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I just found this code which allows me to navigate between divs with the same class with just a click on the next/prev buttons instead of scrolling, but the thing is, the buttons are trigged through a specific text and I want to make trigger through classes instead, something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="nextButton">next</a>
<a href="#" class="prevButton">prev</a>
```

Although the jquery seems to be trigger the class `.display` and then checks the text if it is "next" or "prev" here's the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ufaLefjw/) and the code below:

```
$('div.section').first();

$('a.display').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

  var t = $(this).text(),
  that = $(this);

if (t === 'next' && $('.current').next('div.section').length > 0) {
    var $next = $('.current').next('.section');
    var top = $next.offset().top;

    $('.current').removeClass('current');     
    $(function () {
           $next.addClass('current');
           $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.current').offset().top }, 'slow');

    });
} else if (t === 'prev' && $('.current').prev('div.section').length > 0) {
    var $prev = $('.current').prev('.section');
    var top = $prev.offset().top;

    $('.current').removeClass('current');

    $(function () {
           $prev.addClass('current');
           $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.current').offset().top }, 'slow');
    });
} 
});
```

I want to trigger these buttons by classes so I can Exchange it from text to images, to insert images to be the navigator instead the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple way to do this is to add IDs to the `<a>` tags

```
<a href="#" class="nextButton" id="next">next</a>
<a href="#" class="prevButton" id="prev">prev</a>
```

and then update the `var t` to like to the IDs

```
var t = $(this).attr('id');
```

pay attention to the `if` `else if` as it checks the value of `t` so whatever you set the IDs to you need to edit the `if`s

e.g.

```
HTML:
<a href="#" id="foo" class="display Next">next1</a><br>
<a href="#" id="bar" class="display Prev">prev2</a>

JS:
var t = $(this).attr('id');
...
if (t === 'foo' && $('.current').next('div.section').length > 0) {
...
} else if (t === 'bar' && $('.current').prev('div.section').length > 0) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. The key is on `var t = $(this).text()`, this `var t` used as the checker. If `var t`'s value was `next`, it'll scroll down and also `prev` will scroll up.

So you just have to give `var t` value `next` or `prev`. Here I declare `next` and `prev` as image `id`.

This is the change of the script `var t = $(this).attr('id')`. It's mean `$(this)` refer to `a` whose clicked with these function. And `attr('id')` refering to `a`'s **id**

Now you can add `img` tag inside `a` link with **id** value `next` and `prev`

I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ufaLefjw/2/